# Get Chat History From Zopim iOS Chat SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, chat, zendesk

How do i get chat history for Zoipm chat iOS SDKs, i am logging using anonymous user using default controller, is there any pre-config to be set to get this.

Answer (score 1):

From an end-user's perspective, there is no way of seeing a chat history. Each chat is treated more like a ticket as it creates a ticket with the transcript upon completion. A chat transcript can be sent to the end-user. 
I suppose the end-user could look through their ticket history and effectively see the chats alongside their other submitted tickets.

Comment: The transcript is the first comment in the ticket that is created.